# Merge tags [graphlab] and [turi-create]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Graphlab Create was renamed to Turi Create after the company renamed itself to Turi.  The company was taken over by Apple, which open-sourced Turi Create at: https://github.com/apple/turicreate

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphLab#Turi

I suggest the two tags [graphlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphlab) and [turi-create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turi-create) be merged and made into synonyms.